# Recuperar Dados do Firebase com vários child

Tags: android, firebase

Estou utilizando esta estrutura para salvar os dados:

```
    private void salvar() {
    Protocolo protocolo = new Protocolo();
    protocolo.setAssunto(edtAssunto.getText().toString());
    protocolo.setnProtocolo(edtNProtocolo.getText().toString());
    protocolo.setNomeEmpresa(edtNomeEmpresa.getText().toString());

  databaseReference.child(user.getUid()).child("Protocolos").child(protocolo
       .getNomeEmpresa()).child(protocolo.getAssunto()).setValue(protocolo);
        limparCampos();
    }
```

mas na hora de trazer os dados do `Firebase`, não consigo usar a estrutura correta para trazer o id do usuário, em seguida o nó "protocolo", em seguida a empresa, em seguida o assunto com suas informações. Estou usando esta estrutura para trazer as informações do `Firebase`, e com isso minha `Listview` não exibe nada:

```
    private void inicia() {
    inicializaFirebase();
    final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista_protocolos);
    final List<Protocolo> listaProtocolo = new ArrayList<>();

        databaseReference.child(user.getUid()).child("Protocolos").child("aqui preciso por a empresa")
    .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot objSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Protocolo protocolos = objSnapshot.getValue(Protocolo.class);
                listaProtocolo.add(protocolos);
                ArrayAdapter<Protocolo> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>
                        (ProtocolosActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listaProtocolo);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
            if (listaProtocolo.size() < 1) {
                alert("Você ainda não tem nenhum protocolo cadastrado");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }


    });
}
```

o que devo fazer?

esta é a estrutura do Firebase:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Porque estás a utilizar setValue(protocolo)?

Comment: `Protocolo` é minha instância. ai o `setValue` está salvando meu objeto `protocolo` dado no `Firebase`

Comment: Tens de ir por partes senão é complicado. Primeiro: antes de fazer isto: listaProtocolo.add(protocolos); consegues imprimir algum dado de protocolos? Ou não?. Segundo: o datareference  que estás a definir chega até onde? Podes imprimir com o Log.d e fazer debug para perceber até onde estas a chegar na estrutura do Firebase.

Comment: Você pode mostrar a classe `Protocolo`?

Answer (score 0):

Você está inicializando o adapter várias vezes dentro do ciclo `forEach`. Inicialize apenas uma vez quando o ciclo terminar:

```
databaseReference.child(user.getUid()).child("Protocolos").child("aqui preciso por a empresa")
    .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot objSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Protocolo protocolos = objSnapshot.getValue(Protocolo.class);
                listaProtocolo.add(protocolos);
            }
            if (listaProtocolo.size() < 1) {
                alert("Você ainda não tem nenhum protocolo cadastrado");
            }
            else
            {
                ArrayAdapter<Protocolo> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>
                    (ProtocolosActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listaProtocolo);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }


    });
```